# how to get the exact name of downloading video from python script

Tags: python, urllib2

```
url = "http://r2---sn-pgpq5-gv8e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?beids=%5B9452306%5D&sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&dur=18.250&itag=18&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1488221864&lmt=1417031606585030&upn=GKIFYrlNn_U&source=youtube&id=o-ADqh1mH-ZsRDFnyLkiBlBWkyMjV76jLUJ6q_ZdYUsoZ4&ratebypass=yes&pl=24&mm=31&mn=sn-pgpq5-gv8e&key=yt6&ip=91.222.120.113&signature=B3E780A72E0AA7C86D1562EE983283E7AEB0D35A.68FE2B8E21DA731E56AD6B44E658D5F61501890C&ipbits=0&ms=au&mt=1488200127&initcwndbps=3640000&mv=m&title=20+second+video"

import urllib, urlparse,time

split = urlparse.urlsplit(url)

filename = split.path.split("/")[-1]
```

it gives the filename as videoplayback
but it should be 20 second video

how to solve it

Comment: I think you're looking for [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)`(url)['title']`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to extract the parameter `title` from the query string of your URL. In order to do this, one might use the function [`urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse). The query string is then available via the attribute `query` as shown in the code snippet below.

In the next step, it is necessary to parse as well as decode the query string itself. Although it might be tempting to do it *ab initio*, I would recommend the function `parse_qs` from the same module. This function returns a dictionary encapsulating all parameters/variables found in the query string. However, or a given parameter name, there might be multiple values present - that's way `params['title']` below is in general a list. Nevertheless, for the URL in question, there is only one value of "20 second video".

Finally, note that for Python 3.X, it's necessary to replace the import statement with `from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlsplit`.

```
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit

url = ...

parts = urlsplit(url)
params = parse_qs(parts.query)
print(params['title'][0])
```

Comment: @ashish zip files?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DimaSan couldn't agree more - I have updated the answer... :)